# Data Annotation: "labeling" target vs features

Tags: nlp

I understand how one would use a data annotation tool to label targets for a given sentence, for example though, I'm not clear on how placing labels on features can be used to improve model performance.  For example, in [this text annotation tool](https://literature-review.doccano.coronawhy.org/demo/named-entity-recognition/) , you can add "labels" to a body of text like *person, location, event ...etc* .  Given that you must create Word Embeddings to work with the data, and the vector representation is not human-readable, how would you be able to improve model performance by annotating feature variables?

Answer (score 1):

Those labels are not primarily for features, those labels are primarily for targets. Person, location, and event for targets for [named-entity recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) (NER).